# Customize the HTML <input> element with type="file"

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input, tailwind-css

On the site (written in React), in one of the fields it is possible for the user to select a file from their computer and accordingly see the path (file name).

I implemented this field using HTML input with type="file"...

```
         <div className="inline-flex w-full justify-between">
          <input
            id="fileInput"
            onChange={chooceFile}
            type="file"
            className={clsxm(
              'w-full text-sm',
              'text-[#FFFFFF] file:float-right file:mr-0 file:text-[#FFFFFF]',
              'file:bg-[grey]',
              'file:px-3 file:text-xs',
              'file:font-medium '
            )}
          />
        </div>
```

...and with your help I would like to customize this field. In this regard, I have two related questions:

1. How to change the default label on the button from "Choose File" to "Any text"
2. How to change the default label when no file is selected from "No file chosen" to "Please, choice file"

Comment: You can't (and this exact question, pictures and all, was asked before very recently). The only way to do it is to basically stretch this input over your design and setting its opacity to `0`, which means it still functions the same but you can't see it. Then you can use the details gleaned from `change` and `input` events to change the contents of your visualisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it in React using tailwind

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [asset, setAsset] = useState("");

  const handleAsset = (e) => {
    setAsset(e.target.files[0].name);
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-6/12 mx-auto bg-gray-800 text-white rounded-sm">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between p-2">
        <h3 className="text-white">{asset ? asset : "Please, choice file"}</h3>
        <label htmlFor="file" className="cursor-pointer">
          <div className="bg-gray-400 gap-1.6 px-2 flex  items-center font-normal border-2 border-black">
            <span>Any text</span>
          </div>
          <input
            id="file"
            type="file"
            className="hidden"
            onChange={handleAsset}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really great answer. I had to redo a lot myself, but I understood your approach. Just a small clarification: is it possible to make it so that the window for selecting files opens when you click only the <span>Any text</span> button?

Comment: My pleasure! Yeah! It's possible, and I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to simply overlay the input over your visualisation of it, since the input does nothing but select a file and display that feedback. You can easily mimick this behaviour as such in pure HTML, CSS and a little bit of javascript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll( '.file-input' ).forEach(fileInputWrapper => {
  
  const text = fileInputWrapper.querySelector( 'span' );
  const input = fileInputWrapper.querySelector( 'input' );
    
  input.addEventListener( 'change', event => {
      
    if( input.files.length === 1 ) text.textContent = input.files[0].name;
    else if( input.files.length > 1 ) text.textContent = `${input.files.length} files selected`;
    else input.textContent = 'Please, choice file';
    
  })
  
})
```

```css
.file-input {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}
.file-input input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.file-input span {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-input">
  <input multiple type="file" />
  <span>Please, choice file</span>
  <button>Any Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question and for the answer you provided. Tell me, is it possible to apply your approach using react and tailwind?

Comment: Yes, this is incredibly simple, basic code. Don't forget: react is built _on top_ of Javascript, and Tailwind is build _on top_ of CSS, so this stuff _should_ also work in there. Sadly enough, I am not a React/Tailwind developer (I like to know whats happening inside my code), so I can't exactly show you a react/tailwind implementation here. But from my experience with both, it seems that you could easily make this a component in both frameworks.